# Laravel 5.* agregar hash propio

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

he creado un helper con una funcion propia para hashear el password(de nombre CustomHash) y registra bien pero no loguea, siguiendo un tutorial de preguntas similares hice lo siguiente:

Cree una carpeta libraries => App\libraries la cual contiene 2 archivos:

- CustomHasher.php
- CustomHashServiceProvider.php

el archivo CustomHasher.php se ve asi:

```
<?php

namespace Libraries;

class CustomHasher implements Illuminat\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher {

    /**
     * Hash the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return array   $options
     * @return string
     */

    public function make($value, array $options = array()) {
        return hash('customHash', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Check the given plain value against a hash.
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @param string $hashedValue
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */

     public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
         return $this->make($value) === $hashedValue;
     }

     /**
      * Check if the given hash has been using the given options.
      * @param string $hashedValue
      * @param array $options
      * @return bool
      */

      public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
          return false;
      }

}
```

El archivo CustomHashServiceProvider.php se ve asi:

```
<?php
namespace Libraries;

use Libraries\SHAHasher;
use Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider;

class SHAHashServiceProvider extends Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        $this->app['hash'] = $this->app->share(function () {
            return new CustomHasher();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides() {
        return array('hash');
    }

}
```

mi app/helpers.php

```
<?php

function customHash($value) {
    $value = strtoupper(
         sha1(
             sha1($value, true)
         )
    );
    $value = '*' . $value;
    return $value;
}
```

modifique el composer.json para cargar mis librerias

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        // ...

        "app/libraries"
    ]
},
```

entonces en App\config\app.php Providers comente:

```
//'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
```

y puse debajo:

```
'CustomHashServiceProvider',
```

luego corri en consola

```
composer dump-autoload
```

y me tira el siguiente error:

```
FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'CustomHashServiceProvider' not found
```

que me falta o que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Voy a explicarte la forma como funciona el login en Laravel y tu determinas cual es el mejor camino para lograr lo que deseas, que clases extender, etc:

Todo empieza después de las validaciones y de recibir los datos en **Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers** , en el método login():

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

A continuación, en la siguiente línea es donde se realiza la verificación, o el "intento" de autenticación:

```
if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
```

Esta línea nos lleva a **Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard** , al métood attempt():

```
/**
 * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @param  bool   $remember
 * @param  bool   $login
 * @return bool
 */
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = true)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
        if ($login) {
            $this->login($user, $remember);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // If the authentication attempt fails we will fire an event so that the user
    // may be notified of any suspicious attempts to access their account from
    // an unrecognized user. A developer may listen to this event as needed.
    if ($login) {
        $this->fireFailedEvent($user, $credentials);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Aquí nos importa la siguiente línea, en la cual se determina si las credenciales ingresadas son validas o no:

```
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
```

Eso nos lleva al método que está justo después del que estamos analizando (en el mismo archivo):

```
/**
 * Determine if the user matches the credentials.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return bool
 */
protected function hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)
{
    return ! is_null($user) && $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
}
```

Este método nos lleva al método validateCredentials() del proveedor, el cual puede estar localizado en:

- **Illuminate\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider**
- **Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider**

Según la configuración de tu aplicación, en cualquiera de los dos casos, el contenido del método es el mismo:

```
/**
 * Validate a user against the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

Aquí la segunda línea del método nos lleva al método check() del proveedor del hasher, el cual se encuentra en **Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher**:

```
/**
 * Check the given plain value against a hash.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  string  $hashedValue
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return bool
 */
public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
{
    if (strlen($hashedValue) === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return password_verify($value, $hashedValue);
}
```

Como puedes ver finalmente se usa la función de php [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) para verificar la clave ingresada, por lo cual puedes intentar haciendo un override de este método o utilizando extensiones de los métodos que lo llaman, entre tantas otras posibilidades como reemplazar el Hasher. También podrías crear un servicio para este efecto.

Comment: wow gracias : analizando las funciones importantes serian function make y  Hasher::needsRehash o la cosa es con password_verify()?? xd

Comment: Por favor lee la respuesta bien, ahí están expuestos los métodos implicados.

Comment: no entiendo tu acertijo hombre porque no mejor dar una respuesta directa